# How can I find all path of a graph(no loop) with a fix end node?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I want to find all path start with node a and end with node b.

Now my solution is that start from a to exec DFS and select path ends with b.

The complexity is O(egde + node), can it be optimized to O(path + node)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DFS has O(n), it means `linear` complexity, it cannot be improved in non-sorted graphs.

Comment: how can it be opted with sorted graph?

Comment: Well binary search trees are also graphs, and you can have O(log n) complexity there. For example : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Comment: what is the complexity of top sort a graph?

Comment: I dont understand a question... You mean "what is the best complexity possible?"

Comment: I don't think xunzhang is asking for a sub-linear solution. I think he's asking for something linear in a different (potentially non-linearly smaller) variable, though my guess is he can't have that either. I think he only wants to pay asymptotically for the edges that are needed, not for ones that aren't used in any paths, hence O(path + node) rather than O(edge + node).

Comment: @libik - [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) is linear time. Also, to break the cycles "the right way" you may need to identify the maximal strongly connected components and topologically sort those. I don't know that much about that, but certainly one common algorithm (Tarjans) is O(|E| + |V|) and is based on depth-first searching. There is a mention of a "path-based strong component algorithm" on the [Wikipedia page for Tarjans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm).

Comment: @libik - if that gives you your O(path + node), and the topological sort is then done on a DAG with O(path) edges instead of the original one with O(edge) edges, maybe you can achieve your goal. Interesting, but outside my current knowledge.